# Finding the inverse of a function

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials, scoping, inverse

I am to solve for $r(\rho)$ given the function,

```
ρAsymp[r_, b_, q_] := 
  1/(1 - q) Gamma[1/(1 - q)]/Gamma[(q - 2)/(q - 1)] r Sqrt[1 - (b/r)^(1 - q)]
```

This can be solved in a straightforward way by converting this into a quadratic equation and use `Solve` to find for the root corresponding to $r(\rho)$ for every value of $q$. But I have difficulty implementing the `InverseFunction` to this problem.

Can someone help me with this? Also, I want to scan $r(\rho)$ for all values of $q<1$, how can I implement this by using a `Module`?

Comment: Recommend that you change your definition to `\[Rho]Asymp[r_, b_, q_] := 
 1/(1 - q) Gamma[1/(1 - q)]/Gamma[(q - 2)/(q - 1)] r Sqrt[
     1 - (b/r)^(1 - q)] // FullSimplify // Evaluate` which will be simplified to `Sqrt[1 - (b/r)^(1 - q)]*r`

Comment: I did not see that. Thank you for pointing out. Is there an efficient way of getting $r(\rho)$? for all allowed values of $q$?

Comment: Have you tried using `FullSimplify` on your function? The gamma functions all disappear and I get `ρ = r*Sqrt[1-(b/r)^(1-q)]`. Doesn't solve your problem though.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the examples in the documentaion you could do the following:

```
g = InverseFunction[Function[{r, b, q}, ρAsymp[r, b, q]], 1, 3]
```

which gives the inverse of `ρAsymp[r, b, q]`, a function of `3` arguments, with respect to it's first argument `r`. Evaluation is then

```
g[1, 2, 3]
```

> `Sqrt[2]`

The function `g` may now be used as a usual function.

Comment: What about symbolically? If i only specify, $b$ and $q$

Comment: @user583893 sadly that doesn't work for this particular function and my suggested solution.

Answer (score 1):

This function shows a very different behavior depending on parameters. Decide which parameter combinations are relevant for you with the help of a graphical overview.

```
Manipulate[
  ParametricPlot[{Sqrt[1 - (b/r)^(1 - q)] r /. q -> s/t, r}, {r, -10, 10}, 
    AxesLabel -> {"rho", "r"}, AspectRatio -> 1], 
  {{b, -2}, -5, 5}, 
  {{s, 3}, Join[Range[-5, 5], {1/Pi, Pi, 10 Pi, -1/Pi, -Pi, -10 Pi}]}, 
  {t, Range[5]}]
```

[image]